# DateTime format for unsupported in jdk locale

Tags: java, datetime, locale

This question about DateFormat.getDateInstance(int, Locale). What date pattern i get, if send unsupported in jdk locale? What does it depend?
Simple:

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale("qq", "QQ")).format(currentDate)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get current date in following format:
mm/dd/yy
without locale settings.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if it explained why.

Comment: Locale: For backward compatibility reasons, this constructor does not make any syntactic checks on the input.
And used default locale for OS.

Comment: Please use the gray “edit” link at the bottom of your answer to directly add the information to your answer.